# Create PowerBI Dax Custom Column Equivalent of SQL Case When column contains not in list

Tags: powerbi, dax

In PowerBI when creating a custom column how do I reconstruct the SQL case-when statement below similar to a multiple clause if-then-else statement or switch statement. This also contain AND, OR and checking whether strings exist in some list (in this case currency names)

```
Case
    When Account = 2 and Currency in ('EUR','GBP') then 'Europe'
    When Account = 3 and Currency NOT in ('USD','JPY') then 'Emerging Market'
    When Account = 4 then 'Account 4'
    When code like '123%' then 1
    When code like '%222' then 2
    Else Country_Name
    End as my_custom_column
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated column :

```
my_custom_column = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    Account = 2 && Currency IN { "EUR", "GBP" } && NOT CONTAINSSTRING(CITY_NAME, "YORK"), "Europe",
    Account = 3 && Currency NOT IN { "USD", "JPY" }, "Emerging Market",
    Account = 4, "Account 4",
    LEFT(code, 3) = "123", "1",  //  'like '123%'' can be traslated to starts with '123'
    RIGHT(code, 3) = "222", "2", // Assuming 'like '%222'' can be traslated to starts with ends with '222'
    Country_Name
)
```

Know more about [SWITCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax) in DAX.

Comment: Note that DAX in Power BI supports `Currency IN { "EUR", "GBP" }`.

Comment: @AlexisOlson yes I totally agree I updated the code. Just I used for multiple values

Comment: What if I want to add something similar to SQL's: AND CITY_NAME NOT LIKE '%YORK%'

Comment: @dingo just add && NOT CONTAINSSTRING(CITY_NAME, "YORK"), "Europe"